# Ignore elements in overflow:auto element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an HTML structure below:

```
<div style="overflow:auto;" id="wrap">
    <div id="text">content</div>
    <div id="a"> </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to have the overflow only take the size of #text into account and ignore #a, even if #a overflows further? I can't put #a outside the wrap DIV. I'm fine with using javascript if that is the only option.

EDIT: Here is an example of what I have, to show what I'm asking more clearly: http://jsfiddle.net/mAHMb/

Comment: The issue is, I don't want to be able to scroll to #a. The only thing that should influence the scroll, is the height of #text. I'm not sure if that is possible, but I'm just trying to verify that.

Comment: You want div "_a_" to be fixed at the bottom?

Comment: #a shouldn't effect how far #wrap scrolls on overflow.

Comment: And reason you just do not hide it if it should not be scrolled to? Or remove it from the flow: `#a{ position: absolute; }`

Comment: It's a picture that is positioned relative to #wrap, but if the browser is re-sized past the bottom of the picture, I don't need a scroll bar to see all the way to the bottom. I only need to be able to scroll to the bottom of #text. I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could help?:

Please try adding `overflow-y:auto;` to #text then set its heigth, remove #wrap height and you should be able to scroll #text without scrolling #a.

Here's the jsfiddle sample: http://jsfiddle.net/R4QWP/